# Size of the layout depending of the number of features

Tags: qgis, features, expression, layouts, paper

I have a point layer named `'observation'`, with different attributes and one called `"Année"`. My project also have a variable called `@Année`.

In the layout, I have a A0 page (1189x841), but I want an extra space to put my attribute table (1cm for each row). So I'm trying to calculate the size with this formula, and it's worked fine:

```
841 + (10 * layer_property('Observation', 'feature_count'))
```

My problem is that my attribute table shows only the observations for the given year (`@Année`), with this formula:

```
to_string(year("Année")) LIKE @Année
```

How can I adapt `layer_property('Observation', 'feature_count')` to add a filter, so it will count only the observation for a given year?

(EDIT)
I tried the solution with `aggregate`, but it doesn't work, cause it says "No feature was found on this layer to evaluate the expression", so I can't click on OK.
[image]

(EDIT2)
The expression works to calculate a field for exemple:
[image]
But as an expression to set the size of the page, I still have the problem... and it's exactly the same expression:
[image]

Comment: Remove `filter:=to_string(year("Année")) LIKE to_string(@Année)` and trailing coma at the end of `expression:=...` line to see if it works without `filter`. It's the equivalent of `layer_property('Observation', 'feature_count')`. The goal is to sort out where is the issue

Comment: I still have the same issue, even if I removed the filter.

Comment: I do not have it in both cases, with & without filter. If it does not work without filter, I wonder where the issue could be

Comment: OK, with this expression, I have something: `aggregate('aa_6d49a2f5_1d8a_478d_8a79_96d0b1af30a8', aggregate:= 'count', expression:='Année du relevé')`.

Comment: So the field value for the expression must be between ', and not ".

Comment: But I still can't filtered my expression... either ' or " still gives me an error!

Comment: You may try hard coded value for year e.g `filter:=to_string(year('2012-03-01')) LIKE to_string(@Année)` considering you have a match with your `@Année` variable (you may need to edit `'2012-03-01'`)

Comment: If I hard code the year, it's not anymore a filter for my attribute table. I need to test if my "Année du relevé" is equal to my variable @Année, to count only those field.

Comment: I was able to solve the error with this: `aggregate(layer:='aa_6d49a2f5_1d8a_478d_8a79_96d0b1af30a8', aggregate:= 'count', expression:='Année du relevé',
filter:=to_string(year('Année du relevé')) LIKE @Année)`. But the result is wrong... it should be 5, but it always gives me 0, even if I set a simple expression.

Comment: Hard coded solution wasn't for production but for debugging purpose

Comment: OK, sorry! I tested, but it always gives me 0. I set @Année at 2021, and the expression is `aggregate(layer:='aa_6d49a2f5_1d8a_478d_8a79_96d0b1af30a8',aggregate:= 'count',expression:='Année du relevé', filter:= to_string(year(2021-03-03)) LIKE  @Année )`. Normally, I have 10 features in my table.

Comment: Even if I do this: `aggregate(layer:='aa_6d49a2f5_1d8a_478d_8a79_96d0b1af30a8',aggregate:= 'count',expression:='Année du relevé', filter:= to_string(year(2021-03-03)) LIKE  '2021' )`.

Comment: And `aggregate(layer:='aa_6d49a2f5_1d8a_478d_8a79_96d0b1af30a8',aggregate:= 'count',expression:='Année du relevé', filter:= to_string(year('2021-03-03')) LIKE  '2021' )` ? PS: work in this case

Comment: No, it gives me also 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following (tested)

```
with_variable('Année', '2019',
  aggregate(
    layer:='Observation',
    aggregate:='count',
    expression:="any_existing_field_name_from_observation_layer",
    filter:=to_string(year("Année")) LIKE to_string(@Année)
  )
)
```

**Edit**:

Unable to make things work in the expression for page size, you can try to use the custom Python function

```
from datetime import datetime

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def get_count_filtered(layer_name, field_name, variable_val_name, feature, parent, context):
    """ Returns the value of the variable 'var_name' 
        Example usage: env('user_full_name') """
    project = QgsProject.instance()
    layer = project.mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
    variable_val = QgsExpressionContextUtils.projectScope(project).variable(variable_val_name)
    vals = [str(feat[field_name]) for feat in layer.getFeatures() if feat[field_name] is not None]
    vals = [d for d in vals if str(datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d').year) in variable_val]
    return len(vals)
```

Then use in the expression

```
get_count_filtered('Observation', 'Année du relevé', 'Année')
```

Comment: It doesn't work. See the edit above.

Comment: See my edit, replaced `expression:="",` with `expression:='whatever',`. It could also be `expression:="any_existing_field_name",`

Comment: Sorry, but I still have the same issue... Did you test the expression where we set the size of the page? Cause if I use this expression to calculate a field in a layer, it's work! But not to generate the size of the page?!?? See above for edit2.

Comment: No, tested in an expression context. Will look on size of the page and edit then

Comment: With `expression:="any_existing_field_name_from_observation_layer",` in page size and field in layer, it works but the one `expression:='whatever',` not

Comment: But as you can see above (edit2), it doesn't work on my project?!?? I used "Année du relevé" as a field for the expression. I have QGIS 3.16.10!

Comment: I tried the Python expression, but I have the same problem... `No feature found`. I found a workaround by making a virtual layer, and then I make a `layer_property( 'virtual', 'feature_count')`. The problem is when I change the `@Année`, I first need to restart QGIS so that the virtual layer is updated! By changing a project variable, a virtual layer is not update on the fly!

Comment: I've tested the Python expression and contrary to you, it was working in the page size too. Sorry, it does not work for you. I suppose it needs some adaptation

Comment: Don't worry... thank you for your time! You think it's an issue of QGIS, that `aggregate` is not working in page size?

Comment: Maybe. In doubt, open an issue on the tracker https://github.com/qgis/qgis/issues. Providing a minimum sample project to reproduce could help confirm the issue for devs. If not justified or unable to reproduce, they will close it